# How to access Hidden Field of Parent page in the User control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 1 aspx page and 1 user control. I want to access hidden field of aspx page in the code behind of user control page.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Page.FindControl`

```
var hiddenField = this.Page.FindControl("hiddenField") as HiddenField;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

- Expose the hidden field control as a public property of the containing page.
- In the user control, cast Page to the specific type of the containing page.
- Access the property.

I don't really like this approach as it tightly couples the user control with the containing page type, but this seems to happen frequently in web forms.

**Example**

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public HtmlInputHidden MyHiddenField
    {
        get{ return this.hdnField1; }
    }
}

public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected override OnLoad( EventArgs e )
    {
        MyPage p = (MyPage)Page;
        HtmlInputHidden h = p.MyHiddenField;
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Parent Initializes Child**

This example is cleaner in that the child is agnostic of its parent. However, it requires the parent to initialize the child at the right time (which can be tricky with the web form page lifecycle) and requires that the parent have knowledge of the inner workings of the child.

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override OnLoad( EventArgs e )
    {
        this.MyUserControl.Initialize( this.MyHiddenField );
    }
}

public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public void Initialize( HtmlInputHidden input )
    {
        // now child user control has access to the data without needing to know
        // about its parent
    }
}
```

Comment: But you need to know the page type

Comment: @AdrianIftode - depending on how elaborate you wanted to get, you could add a genericized method for setting the parent. You could have the parent implement an interface. Or, you could just hardcode the type of the parent (as my example shows). As I said, I don't like the tight coupling that this promotes.

Comment: the parent page can be accessed via this.Page property, then use FindControl method

Comment: FindControl() will work but it isn't recursive so that's more code...and (in my opinion) having to know the actual ID is even more tightly coupled.

Comment: Agree with the ID. The recursive aspect doesn't change much the things. The implementation would be the same (with an extension method) and you still need to use it (the FindControl method) when the page contains nested controls.

Comment: I added a somewhat cleaner example. In practice, it depends on how many pages you have. Most of my ASP.NET websites have only one main page into which all content is dynamically loaded. In that scenario, it's fine for the child controls to be very knowledgeable of their parent page and any of the methods we are discussing will work. If your site has 500 different ASPX pages, then that's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Yes, the second solution is much better, because of this statement "the child doesn't need to know the parent's type"